# Rotate around a changing origin - Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

So I have an object rotating around an origin point. Once I rotate and then change the origin point. My object seems to jump positions. After the jump it rotates fine... Need help finding the pattern/why it's jumping and what I need to do to stop it.

Here's the rotation code:

```
adjustMapTransform = function (_x, _y) {

    var x = _x + (map.width/2);
    var y = _y + (map.height/2);   


    //apply scale here 
    var originPoint = {
        x:originXInt,
        y:originYInt
    };

    var mapOrigin = {
        x:map.x + (map.width/2),
        y:map.y + (map.height/2)
    };    

    //at scale 1
    var difference = {
        x:mapOrigin.x - originPoint.x,
        y:mapOrigin.y - originPoint.y
    };

    x += (difference.x * scale) - difference.x;
    y += (difference.y * scale) - difference.y;

    var viewportMapCentre = {
        x: originXInt,
        y: originYInt
    }

    var rotatedPoint = {};
    var angle = (rotation) * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var s = Math.sin(angle);
    var c = Math.cos(angle);

    // translate point back to origin:
    x -= viewportMapCentre.x;
    y -= viewportMapCentre.y;

    // rotate point
    var xnew = x * c - y * s;
    var ynew = x * s + y * c;

  // translate point back:
    x = xnew + viewportMapCentre.x -  (map.width/2);
    y = ynew + viewportMapCentre.y - (map.height/2);  

    var coords = {
        x:x,
        y:y
    };

    return coords;
}
```

Also here is a JS Fiddle project that you can play around in to give you a better idea of what's happening.

**EDITED LINK** - Got rid of the originY bug and scaling bug
https://jsfiddle.net/fionoble/6k8sfkdL/13/

Thanks!

Comment: not only that moving y origin has no effect until x has moved as well

Comment: scale also doesn't work as i thought it should, for example, if you scale change origin then scale it wont add new size into previous one but scale all over again as if i centered the map then set the origin then scaled, instead i scaled change origin then scale again.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadUmer . I've edited the JSFiddle with the originY bugfix

Comment: Seems like i need to counter rotate the origin

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xerxesnoble/yt7dbj03/ 

I updated your code so that the map rotates/scales around the changing origin. In fact, your code works just the way it is. I'm just updating the origin on each 'step' of the displayLoop rather than `oninput`. However, this depicts that your problem lies somewhere else: The changing origin point actually translates the maps x/y position inside the `#mapContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of rotation is a consequence of the sign you pick for the elements in your rotation matrix. [This is Rodrigues formula for rotation in two dimensions].  So to rotate in the opposite direction simply subtract your y cosine term rather than your y sine term.

Also you might try looking at different potential representations of your data.

If you use the symmetric representation of the line between your points you can avoid shifting and instead simply transform your coordinates.

Take your origin [with respect to your rotation], c_0,  to be the constant offset in the symmetric form.

You have for a point p relative to c_0:

```
    var A = (p.x - c_0.x);
    var B = (p.y - c_0.y);

 //This is the symmetric form.   
 (p.x - c_0.x)/A = (p.y - c_0.y)/B
```

which will be true under a change of coordinates and for any point on the line (which also takes care of scaling/dilation).

Then after the change of coordinates for rotation you have [noting that this rotation has the opposite sense, not the same as yours].

```
  //This is the symmetric form of the line incident on your rotated point
  //and on the center of its rotation
  ((p.x - c_0.x) * c + (p.y - c_0.y) * s)/A = ((p.x - c_0.x) * s - (p.y - c_0.y) * c)/B
```

so, multiplying out we get

```
  (pn.x - c_0.x) * B * c + (pn.y - c_0.y) * B * s = (pn.x - c_0.x) * A * s - (pn.y - c_0.y) * A * c
```

rearrangement gives

```
  (pn.x - c_0.x) * (B * c - A * s) = - (pn.y - c_0.y) * (B * s + A * c)

 pn.y = -(pn.x - c_0.x) * (B * c - A * s) /  (B * s + A * c) + c_0.y;
```

for any scaling.

Comment: Are the comparison statements meant to check if the values are correct?